# Docker mount host dir as read-only with correct SELinux label

Tags: docker, selinux

Is there a way to have docker mount a volume with the correct SELinux label as well as mounting read-only?

I know they are possible individually but cannot find any trace of anyone trying (or wanting) both effects at once.

I don't see a reason why they should be mutually exclusive.

For clarity: What I am looking for is a combination of the :ro and :Z modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying multiple flags for volumes is a bit hidden in the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

> The third field is optional, and is a comma-separated list of options, such as ro, consistent, delegated, cached, z, and Z.

So, if you need multiple flags for selinux and readonly you should be able to separate them with commas to `ro,Z`.

```
docker run --rm -v /mountpoint:/data:ro,Z nginx
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been through the documentation, including the page you linked, several times but still missed it.